# Does being left handed or right handed affect a mobs attributes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I noticed while I was playing that some zombies held items in their right hand and some held items in their left hand.  Is there any difference in being left or right handed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is merely a visual change.

The `LeftHanded` byte tag determines whether or not the mob's mainhand is its left or right hand (when set to 1, it is left-handed). The equipment held within `HandItems` remains the same. That is, the first record is the mainhand and the second is the offhand (in both cases, the stone is the mainhand).

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~ {HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:1b},{id:"minecraft:dirt",Count:1b}],LeftHanded:1b}

/summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~ {HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:1b},{id:"minecraft:dirt",Count:1b}],LeftHanded:0b}
```